# converting mongoDB query to Java (Distinct with sort)

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to create java code for the below mongoDB query. Since i am new to mongoDB cananyone help on this

```
db.getCollection('dum_stats').distinct("engineNo").sort();
```

Comment: please add anything you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample example for Mongo 3.x version.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db  = mongoClient.getDatabase("yourdb")
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("dum_stats");
FindIterable<Document> distinct = collection.distinct("engineNo", Document.class);
distinct.sort(Sorts.descending("engineNo"));
```

Comment: There is no method as sort. FindIterable<Document> distinct = collection.distinct("engineNo", Document.class).sort(null);

Comment: Updated. Try now.

Comment: Yes it is available, but it expects a Bson object as argument, i want to provide sort like distinct.sort(-1);

Comment: Hi, @user2683814 
Your solution is giving me an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from DistinctIterable<Document> to FindIterable<Document>" for collection.distinct.
What should I do regarding it? Thanks in advance.